# MySQL Query Problem with Alias and Aggregate Functions

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, mysql-error-1111

I have a troublesome MySQL query as follows:

```
SELECT camera_id, ((avg(low_price) + avg(high_price)) / 2) as avg_price
FROM camera_general, camera_products
WHERE camera_id = ir_camera_id
AND dp_post_dt IS NOT NULL
AND dp_post_dt NOT LIKE '0000%'
AND currently_manufactured = 'Yes'
AND ((no_of_sellers >= 0) OR ((TO_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE) - TO_DAYS(dp_post_dt)) < 120))
AND avg_price < 150 
AND camera_id != 1411
AND camera_id != 9
ORDER BY rand();
```

This one produced the "Unknown column 'avg_price' in 'where clause'" error. I understand this is because column aliases are not allowed in the WHERE clause. (Correct me if I'm wrong with any of this as I go, please.)

So, I tweaked the query like so:

```
SELECT camera_id, ((avg(low_price) + avg(high_price)) / 2) as avg_price
FROM camera_general, camera_products
WHERE camera_id = ir_camera_id
AND dp_post_dt IS NOT NULL
AND dp_post_dt NOT LIKE '0000%'
AND currently_manufactured = 'Yes'
AND ((no_of_sellers >= 0) OR ((TO_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE) - TO_DAYS(dp_post_dt)) < 120))
AND ((avg(low_price) + avg(high_price)) / 2) < 150 
AND camera_id != 1411
AND camera_id != 9
ORDER BY rand();
```

Replacing the alias with the actual calculation and this query produced the error: "Invalid use of group function". I understand this is because the avg() can't happen until after the WHERE clause has done its processing.

So then I tried:

```
SELECT camera_id, ((avg(low_price) + avg(high_price)) / 2) as avg_price
FROM camera_general, camera_products
ORDER BY rand();
HAVING camera_id = ir_camera_id
AND dp_post_dt IS NOT NULL
AND dp_post_dt NOT LIKE '0000%'
AND currently_manufactured = 'Yes'
AND ((no_of_sellers >= 0) OR ((TO_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE) - TO_DAYS(dp_post_dt)) < 120))
AND avg_price < 150 
AND camera_id != 1411
AND camera_id != 9;
```

Replacing the WHERE with the HAVING and it produced this error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING camera_id = ir_camera_id'".

And at this point, I feel like I am shooting in the dark trying to make this query work. Would someone guide me in the right direction to make this a functioning query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Even though you can use `WHERE` to specify join condition, it's better to do in `LEFT[INNER] JOIN` clause.
2. If you want to filter by non-aggregate field, put the filter into `WHERE`, if you need to filter by aggregate, move condition into `HAVING`
3. While using aggregate and non-aggregates in the same query, don't forget `GROUP BY`.

   `SELECT camera_id, ((avg(low_price) + avg(high_price)) / 2) as avg_price
   FROM camera_general

   INNER JOIN camera_products ON (camera_id = ir_camera_id)

   WHERE  dp_post_dt IS NOT NULL

   AND dp_post_dt NOT LIKE '0000%'

   AND currently_manufactured = 'Yes'

   AND ((no_of_sellers >= 0) OR ((TO_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE) - TO_DAYS(dp_post_dt)) < 120))

   AND camera_id != 1411
   AND camera_id != 9

   GROUP BY camera_id

   HAVING avg_price < 150

   ORDER BY rand();`

Comment: Thank you - this worked. I understood (looked up) #2 and #3. However, I'm still a little fuzzy as to why it is better to do a a LEFT[INNER] JOIN?

Comment: Join conditions in `WHERE` is an old syntax (ANSI SQL 1989). It supports only cross and inner join (for outer joins different servers have different extensions, e.g. TSQL has `*=` AND `=*`) . `JOIN` keyword was introduced in SQL 1992 and supports outer joins. Using `JOIN` makes your query clear and it's considered as a good style to use it while specifying join condition.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the explanation and the help!

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER` clause should go after `HAVING` clause. (besides you put a semicolon `;` after `ORDER BY rand()` then continued with `HAVING`, which is actually a start of another query, since the first got ended with the `;`).

Comment: Thank you. The semicolon was a mix up from rearranging everything from before. However, moving the ORDER clause after HAVING did work to fix the one problem, but forced me to add all the non-aggregate columns used in the HAVING clause to the GROUP BY clause.